# What's uniform block signed permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, terminology, representation-theory

Let $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $P(n)$ the set of all partitions of [n]. A partition of $[n]$ is non-empty disjoint subsets of [n], called blocks, whose union is $[n]$.

A block permutation of [n] is a bijection $\phi: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{A}, \ \mathcal{B} \in P(n)$ with the same number of blocks. In particular, if $\phi$ maps each block of $\mathcal{A}$ to a block of $\mathcal{B}$ of the same cardinality, then the block permutation $\phi$ is called uniform.

When I read an article, I meet the concept of uniform block signed permutations. But I do not know the concept, can someone interpret what's  uniform block signed permutations? Thanks in advance.